# Android Espresso - assert text on screen against string in resources

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have the following text in strings.xml resources file:

```
<string name="txt_to_assert">My Text</string>
```

Normally in a application code, to use this text and display it on screen, I'm doing the following:

```
getString(R.string.main_ent_mil_new_mileage);
```

At the moment, I'm trying to use this string resource in a UI test written with Espresso. I'm thinking of doing something like that:

```
String myTextFromResources = getString(R.string.main_ent_mil_new_mileage);
onView(allOf(withId(R.id.my_text_on_screen), withText(myTextFromResources))
    .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

However, `getString(...)` method cannot be used here.
Is there a way to get a text from strings.xml resource file and use it in a test written with Espresso?

Comment: I get an error: **Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID**

Answer (score 70):

Use this function:

```
private String getResourceString(int id) {
    Context targetContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
    return targetContext.getResources().getString(id);
}
```

You just have to call it with the id of the string and perform your action:

```
String myTextFromResources = getResourceString(R.string.main_ent_mil_new_mileage);
onView(allOf(withId(R.id.my_text_on_screen), withText(myTextFromResources))
    .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

***EDIT for new Espresso version:**

With new version of Espresso, you should be able to call directly the string resource with a *ViewMatcher*. So first, I recommend to try directly this import

```
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;
```

And then in the code:

```
withText(R.string.my_string_resource)
```

Comment: Nice to read that! you could accept my answer or vote me up mate ;)

Comment: Voted up, but I'm getting messages that votes from users with less than 15 reputation are taken into account, but not shown publicly.

Comment: Your first method is still valid if we want to use equalToIgnoringCase from hamcrest.
Example: onView(allOf(withText(equalToIgnoringCase(getResourceString(R.string.promos_activity_tab_store_))), isCompletelyDisplayed())).perform(click());

Answer (score 9):

`androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry` is deprecated use `androidx.test.core.app.ApplicationProvider`

```
val targetContext: Context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()
val test: String =  targetContext.getResources().getString(R.string. my_text_on_screen)
```

Answer (score 8):

**Kotlin:**

```
var resources: Resources = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext.resources
```

Answer (score 1):

If in case you have to append a text before the String resource, you will have to do it like this

```
val text=getApplicationContext<Context().getResources().getString(R.string.title_tenth_char)
```

now that you have access to text append the string to that